# Google Maps API - disabled on domain using GoogleMapSlider

Tags: google-maps

I am using the app GoogleMapSlider from css-tricks website, everything was working great but yesterday I got this error message: **"Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.**

Then, I tried changing this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBHbK62TIIyLtdO2r7qTjhXND7oh-9M2cA&sensor=true">
```

But still is not working...

Comment: Can you share a URL that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe your key is used for one website.

You can follow this to get another Google map api v3 key:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I fixed the problem, I was using a local version of the script. Also, I made the `sensor="false"` also.

No API KEY needed since v3 no longer requires applying for an API key.